# Unable to capture output from CMD

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, jenkins, virtual-machine

Trying to open CMD in elevated mode and running powershell script.

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process cmd \"/k "PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file ""C:\WIM_Creation.ps1 ""hello"" V7.0E V9.0A""\" -Verb RunAs"
```

Note: Problem is in order to open CMD in elevated mode from current CMD window it redirect to new window in elevated mode and run the command. due to which output is not getting captured in primary CMD window. HENCE NOT GETTING OUTPUT CAPTURED IN JENKINS.

Need to open elevated CMD in current CMD.

Comment: `start-process -RedirectStandardOutput file`

Comment: Why are you running a cmd.exe instance, to run a powershell.exe instance to run a second cmd.exe process to run an elevated powershell.exe process? Can you not just start an elevated powershell.exe process from the initial powershell.exe command, without introducing another cmd.exe instance?

Comment: i use to run the command from host pc in order to achive the automation. `$process =  Start-Process -RedirectStandardOutput "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\vboxmanage.exe" -ArgumentList "guestcontrol `"$vma`" run --exe `"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe`" --username `"InstallerBuildPC`" --password `"harmony1`" --wait-stdout  -- `"/c`" `"C:\test2.bat.lnk`"" -NoNewWindow -wait`  C:\test2.bat.lnk is having admin privelage with code `PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -file ""C:\WIM_Creation.ps1"" `"$Model`" `"$Prev`" `"$Curr`" -wait `  and i need to get output on host machine

Answer (score 1):

- An *elevated* process launched from a *non-elevated* one *invariably* runs in a new window.
- A non-elevated process that launches an elevated one cannot capture its output.

  - The workaround is to make the elevated process *itself* capture its output, by *redirecting it to a file*.
  - Unless the program running in the elevated process itself happens to support that, you must call it *via a shell*, i.e. launch the *shell* elevated, and pass it a command line that invokes the target executable with a shell redirection (`>`)

---

To make your code work:

- You need to add `-Wait` to your [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) `-Verb RunAs` call to ensure that it waits for the elevated process to terminate.

  - This precludes using `cmd /k` in automated execution, as it would create a `cmd.exe` session that *stays open* until closed by the user.
  - While you could use `cmd /c`, there's no reason to create another `cmd.exe` process - just call the nested `powershell` instance directly.
- `*>$env:TEMP\out.txt` is used to capture the elevated `powershell` instance's output in a temporary file, whose content is then output by the outer (non-elevated) instance.

  - Note:

    - The file's content is only output *after* the elevated process has exited, so you won't get realtime feedback; while implementing the latter is possible, it would significantly complicate the solution.
    - Using fixed file name `out.txt` creates the potential for name collisions; ruling those out would require more work.

```bash
powershell -Command "Start-Process -Verb RunAs -Wait powershell '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file C:\WIM_Creation.ps1 \"hello\" V7.0E V9.0A *>$env:TEMP\out.txt'; Get-Content $env:TEMP\out.txt; Remove-Item $env:TEMP\out.txt"
```

Note that I've made some corrections to the use of `"` quotes in your original command, based on what I *think* you're trying to do.

Comment: i use to run the command from host pc in order to achive the automation. `$process =  Start-Process -RedirectStandardOutput "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\vboxmanage.exe" -ArgumentList "guestcontrol "$vma" run --exe "C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" --username "InstallerBuildPC" --password "harmony1" --wait-stdout  -- "/c" "C:\test2.bat.lnk"" -NoNewWindow -wait` C:\test2.bat.lnk is having admin privelage with code `PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -file ""C:\WIM_Creation.ps1"" "$Model" "$Prev" "$Curr" -wait`  and i need to get output on host machine

Comment: @PrateekVerma, I'm not sure what you're trying to say, but note that the solution in this answer outputs the combined stdout + stderr output from the elevated script to the caller. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: ok let me explain my situation we have one VM on hostPC(primary PC) both are windows, we execute some process using this VM. now i have to run DISM tools which required elevated permission. Now scenario is in order to automate we run the ps1 script from hostPC to Triger the another .ps1 file inside the VM(we triggers ps1 using .bat file <test2.bat> in order to elevate permission i use shortcut <tes2.bat.lnk>as admin) everything going fine here we achieve all automation but requirement is :- all process take 6-7hr to execute so we want all output come to hostpc console so progress can be track.

Comment: @PrateekVerma, it sounds like you additionally need to print the output from the elevated process _as it is being produced_. This isn't stated in your question, and this added requirement would significantly complicate the solution. Given that this answer addresses your question as asked, I suggest creating a _new_ question post that focuses on this additional requirement - but be sure to state your requirements in full and use a representative command.